# Is it secure to submit forms this way?

Tags: php, forms

I am using PHP to submit forms on my website. When the action or logic is in another file, I do it this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/group.php?GI=<?php echo $group['ID']; ?>">
```

The constant `ROUTE` is being used to show the root folder, which is something like `http://localhost/example/project`. And the variable `$group` and the `ID` must be sent through the form so we can get this number on `group.php`.

My question is, is it secure to send the information this way or should I apply some kind of filters?

Comment: Where does `$group['ID']` come from? Is there any way for it to contain user input?

Comment: No, `$group['ID']` must be sent through the form so we can get this variable on `group.php`.

Comment: Well, now that I think of it better, as soon as you include it in the query string or even if you place it in a hidden input, you open up a possibility for the user to tamper with it. How you should sanitize this depends on what you'll be using it for.

Comment: I *can* be secure ..  It's  only as secure as your `group.php` scripting is written...  Prepared statements, error handling, try/catch statments etc etc etc ..

Comment: AND .. If you are sending sensitive information in the URL .. Don't.  Best to use POST or SESSIONS to store/send sensitive information.